# Modifying Burndown Chart in TFS 11

Tags: tfs, scrum

Our development methology differs from the default scrum template by Microsoft in a significant fact: We do not measure each individual task but estimate the "stories" (the parent work items). However using the new Beta of TFS 11 i realized that the burndown chart is based only on the estimated tasks. I downloaded the template and looked at the xmls and the reports, however i dont think one is able to modify this behavior with only modifying the template.

Is there a "simple" way to implement this behavior in TFS 11 in only the template?

Answer (score 1):

The TFS 11 tasboard works with the concept of Parent work items and Child work items. Parent work items appears on the backlog. Child work items appear on the taskboard.

The provided templates assume Parent work items are Stories, and child work items are tasks.

You can configure your parents and tasks to be whatever work items you wish, however, you must have a parent and a child work item type defined. For example, you can make your parent work items EPICs and your child work items Stories. But then EPICs woudl appear on your backlog (not Stories)

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: it does not answer my question on how to modify this behavior but it clears up the inner workings a little bit