# How can I configure the TFS 2012 burndown chart to track bugs?

Tags: tfs, burndowncharts

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10353521/117507) the model for the TFS 11 burndown chart is for tasks that a children to stories.

How can I display a burndown chart of the currently opened bugs during a sprint without having to create subordinate work items for them?

Comment: It seems as though they would need to have specific fields added (as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12536132/how-to-add-bugs-to-tfs-2012-task-board) to work on the burndown chart. Is this the only way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way it is intended is that you add tasks as children of the bug as soon as the bug is added to a sprint. These tasks will drive the burndown. This is the same for Product Backlog Items and it is very simple through the web ui. The estimation data in the bug itself will be represented in the release burndown.

Should you want the bug itself to function as a task, you can either:

- Use a task workitem to log bugs. This is very common for bugs found for work that is ongoing in the current sprint. It's just a bit of extra work to achieve 'done'.
- Update the work item definition for bug to have the proper states and fields, and add it to the task category. The [process is mostly described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12536132/how-to-add-bugs-to-tfs-2012-task-board).

You should also keep in mind that bugs found for work that was done in a previous sprint should only be picked up in the current sprint during the sprint planning meeting, or when it is critical to fix it as part of the current sprint. In the first case, treat it as just any other PBI and break it down into tasks. In the second case, go fix it immediately, don't bother about the burndown, the bug is critical and should be fixed *now*.